# Formula address from column and row numbers in SmartXLS (java)

Tags: java, smartxls

How can I get the formula address of a cell knowing the column and the row numbers? I want to use it to link a dynamic data source to a chart. THX

Comment: @AsierAranbarri as you wish.

Comment: @Aboutblank I looked for a method in the documentations provided by SmartXLS that converts the column and row numbers into a formula address but no luck.
This is the method I want to use the address for:

setLinkRange
public void setLinkRange(java.lang.String range,
                         boolean bSeriesInRows)
                  throws java.lang.Exception
Links the chart to the range in the workbook represented by the specified formula.
Parameters:
range - string indicating the range to link to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formatRCNr method:

String rangestr = workBook.formatRCNr(0, 0, false) + ":" + workBook.formatRCNr(2, 2, false);  //A1:C2