# Get Cells position with SmartXLS workbook

Tags: c#, excel, smartxls

I'm using SmartXLS workbook to read an excel file, I can access to the data at index like ::

```
              var workbook = new WorkBook();
                workbook.read(filePath); //read from Excel File
                var dataTable = workbook.ExportDataTable(); //export to DataTable

                var tenderResponseLineData = new List<TenderResponseLine>();

                for (int i = 1; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                { 

Code = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString().Trim(), //Get code
    ProductName = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString().Trim(), //get ProductName
    }
```

Now I want to get the cell position (column letter, position-line) of data such as L4, or B3. I don't know if SmartXLS has this function or not ? I have searched on SmartXLS site but I haven't found information about this

Thanks,

Comment: Please check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567698/formula-address-from-column-and-row-numbers-in-smartxls-java

It may solve your problem.

Comment: @AhmedYahia Thanks, can I have one more question from you, do you know how to disable the header in excel file ? when we export it ?